# How do you pull data from SQL Server to Oracle?

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I'm wanting to take data from a SQL Server table and populate a Oracle table. Right now, my solution is to dump the data into a Excel table, write a macro to create a sql file that I can load into Oracle. The problem with this is I want to automate this process and I'm not sure I can automate this.

Is there an easy way to automate populating a Oracle table with data from a SQL Server table?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Transferring data from Sql Server to Oracle using Excel is like shipping oil from the middle east to America in a canoe.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose it depends on your definition of "easy".

The most robust approach would be to either use [heterogeneous connectivity](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14232/toc.htm) in Oracle to create a database link to the SQL Server database and then pull the data from SQL Server or to create a [linked server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213778%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) in SQL Server that connects to Oracle and then push the data from SQL Server to Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Take a look at MS SQL's SSIS which stands for [SQL Server Integration Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx). SSIS allows all sorts of advanced capabilities, including automated with Sql Server Jobs, for moving data between disparate data sources. In your case, [connecting to Oracle](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jorg_klein/archive/2009/10/15/ssis-connect-to-oracle-on-a-64-bit-machine.aspx) can be achieved a variety of ways.

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to automate this:

1) You can do as Paul suggested and created an SSIS package that will do this and it can be scheduled via SQL Agent,

2) If you don't want to deal with SSIS, you can download the free SQL# (SQLsharp) CLR Library from http://www.SQLsharp.com/ and use the DB_BulkCopy Stored Procedure to do this in a T-SQL Stored Proc which can also be scheduled via SQL Agent.  [note: I am the author of SQL#]

3) You can also set up a Linked Server from SQL Server to Oracle, but this has the draw-back of being a potential security hole.  Of course, you could use an Oracle Login that only has write-access to that single table (or something similar to that).

Answer (score 0):

There are lots and lots of ways to do it. Which you choose depends on your requirements.

- Using Excel is fine if it's a one time thing.
- If it's a once-in-a-while thing, then you could write a simple .NET app that uses a single DataSet and multiple DataAdapters to do the data dump.  [C# code example here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5602835).
- if it's a regular thing, then you could put the above in a Schtasks task, or you could use SSIS.  I think SSIS is an extra-cost option.
- if the requirement is for "online access", then a linked database is probably appropriate.

Comment: SSIS is free. Enterprise Edition comes with additional SSIS tasks. The only cost is the time it takes to create and maintain the packages.

Comment: The link http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/srcview.aspx?dir=data&file=CopyData-TwoOledbDataAdapters.cs seems to be broken